# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in activity onCreate

Tags: java, android, admob, mopub

In a recent release where I added MoPub via Admob ad mediation I am seeing a bunch of ConcurrentModificationException in crash logs. It all seems to be native code and I am on the latest version of all ad related and google/android related libraries. Anyone run in to this before?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3121)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3264)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1955)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7078)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:964)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: 
  at androidx.c.g.put (SimpleArrayMap.java:482)
  at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.hs.a
  at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.hi.onActivityCreated
  at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityCreated (Application.java:245)
  at android.app.Activity.onCreate (Activity.java:1108)
  at androidx.core.app.e.onCreate (ComponentActivity.java:81)
  at androidx.activity.b.onCreate (ComponentActivity.java:149)
  at androidx.fragment.app.c.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:313)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.e.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java:106)
  at com.teamtol.livedota.BaseActivity.onCreate (BaseActivity.java:21)
  at com.teamtol.livedota.RecentGameActivity.onCreate (RecentGameActivity.java:70)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7327)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7318)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1275)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3101)
```

This is what the code looks like up to line 21 of BaseActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

This is what the code looks like up to line 70 of RecentGameActivity

```
public class RecentGameActivity extends BaseActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: We found the same issue on several phones up to Android 9. Do you make use of Firebase Analytics? If yes, which version?

Comment: Having the same issue after I upgraded dependencies.

Comment: @Farasy Yea I see it a lot on Android 9 as well, though a few users on other versions. I'm using Firebase Analytics com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2

Comment: anyone have an idea or scenario to generate this crash?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In our case, we are only seeing the crash with

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2
```

reverting to 17.2.1 has fixed the problem

This happens too if you are using firebase-core:17.2.2, because firebase-analytics is the same library rebranded. Take into account that as per official docs, current usage of firebase-core is deprecated -> https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions

Comment: reverting firebase-analytics to 17.2.1 has fixed our problem. Thanks!

Comment: Reverting firebase-analytics to 17.2.1 has not fixed the problem for us. We've been using `17.2.1` for a while and did not see these crashes. I doubt that the crash is at all related to the `firebase-analytics` library.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I just released a version with 17.2.1. Will update once it's had time in users' hands

Comment: Correction: we reverted firebase-analytics to 17.2.1 but left firebase-core unchanged at 17.2.2 and were still receiving crashes. We then released a version with core also reverted to 17.2.1 and no crashes so far. (I am not sure firebase-core is still needed at all?)

Comment: @PabloA.Martínez Good, we did not see any crashes on 17.2.1 since reverting both core and analytics libraries. Do you happen to know since which version core is deprecated? I couldn’t find a reference to that.

Comment: I changed firebase-core to firebase-analytics 17.2.1 (was a simple name change for me no code changes required) and have no issues now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: i dont import firebase-analytics nor firebase-core and im getting the same error

Comment: Can someone confirm if its fixed in 17.2.3 released on the 28th Feb?

Comment: @Tearsdontfalls I would suggest waiting a bit more, due to known issues found in some updated dependencies last 27th Feb https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Answer (score 20):

Revert your Firebase Core library to:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.1.0'
```

I've seen this crash on both v17.2.1 and v17.2.2, but since reverting to 17.1.0 all has been fine.

I've reported the bug here: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs

**Update**

Thanks @Sébastien, reverting to v17.2.0 should also work:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
```

Comment: In the Firebase Release Notes (https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) they say to replace the firebase-core by firebase-analytics or the libraries that we are using. Have you tried this solution?

Comment: I guess both are almost identical except the title. We found that issue when upgrading from com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.1.0 to 17.2.2

Comment: @Farasy thanks for the reply, I will revert the dependency :|

Comment: Thanks @Jim. Please keep us posted. It seems that `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0` is also exempt of the bug.

Comment: @Sébastien thanks for the info, I'll update my answer to reflect that firebase-core:17.2.0 also works. I had skipped that version altogether and went back to the version that had previously worked for us.

Comment: Version 17.2.1 also works, we did not ever observe a crash on that version, only after upgrading to 17.2.2.

Comment: 17.2.1 is working for me, but I wouldn't blame anyone for reverting back to 17.1.x or 17.2.0. Thanks for the help!

Comment: i dont import firebase-analytics nor firebase-core and im getting the same error

Comment: I import 17.2.2 ads and firebase-analytics, getting ConcurrentModificationException in com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzin.zza + 108(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.2.2:108

Comment: 2nd possible solution is to delay measurement initialization with meta-data https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent#delay_app_measurement_optional

Comment: Can't reproduce the exception but it started to show up on google play crash reports after upgraded from firebase-core:17.2.1 to firebase-core:17.2.2. So instead downgrading to 17.2.1 I'll give a try to @Dmitrijs delay measurement initialization solution.

Comment: @SinanCeylan I delay measurement initialization and downgraded firebase-analytics to 17.2.0, also added play-services-measurement and play-services-measurement-sdk to Gradle to have an exact version of it - 17.1.0, now crash completely gone.

Comment: Fixed on 17.2.3 https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#analytics_v17-2-3

Answer (score 11):

It is finally fixed in 17.2.3:
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#analytics_v17-2-3

Comment: Yepp, fixed for me too!

Answer (score 6):

We've identified the issue, and are working on a fix for the next release of the SDK.

Comment: We are facing the same issue. Please let us know about the progress in fixing this.

Comment: is it fixed with 17.2.3 ?

Comment: @Qbit it is fixed on 17.2.3. https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#analytics_v17-2-3

Comment: Found this issue again on  'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.0'.

Comment: John - do you have a stack trace for this occurrence?

Answer (score 0):

We have recently encountered a similar problem. Error in the Unity Ads adapter for Admob mediation.

Here is our build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:unity:3.4.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:vungle:6.5.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:chartboost:7.5.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:mytarget:5.6.3.0'
implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobmetricalib:3.13.1'
implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobileads:2.142'
implementation 'com.yandex.ads.adapter:admob-mobileads:0.3.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:19.1.0'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.7.2'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

Error in Google Play console:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: 
  at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode (HashMap.java:1453)
  at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next (HashMap.java:1487)
  at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next (HashMap.java:1485)
  at com.google.ads.mediation.unity.UnitySingleton$UnitySingletonListener.onUnityAdsError (UnitySingleton.java:227)
  at com.unity3d.services.ads.configuration.AdsModuleConfiguration$3.run (AdsModuleConfiguration.java:92)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:888)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:213)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8178)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:513)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

Is this problem related to firebase again?

**UPDATE**

It looks like the problem this time is in the UnityAds adapter:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/unity#version-3.4.2.2