# Android crash on activity start in com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

I have Firebase Crashlytics in my app, and recently I started receive strange crashes somewhere in `com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.`

Crashes spread evenly on Os levels and devices and only their common feature in "Proximity On"
according to Firebase.

Maybe this is correlated somehow with update to `com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.5`

Is there something I could do in my code to prevent such behavior?

Full stack trace for said crash:

```
 Caused by java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
       at androidx.collection.SimpleArrayMap.put(SimpleArrayMap.java:444)
       at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzin.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.2.2:108)
       at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzid.onActivityCreated(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.2.2:11)
       at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityCreated(Application.java:189)
       at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:937)
       at com.watabou.noosa.Game.onCreate(Game.java:225)
       at com.watabou.pixeldungeon.RemixedDungeon.onCreate(RemixedDungeon.java:108)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Comment: The stack trace says this is happening in com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.2.2

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59916267/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-in-activity-oncreate Pls also file a bug so google fixes it.