# android overriding onCreate method

Tags: android, oncreate

When creating an `Activity` to android we must override the `onCreate` method and the new method MUST call the `super.onCreate`

My question is does it need to be the **first** statement of the new onCreate?

I've a small framework that inject some code in my activities... it was working fine without major problems

then i made some changes to solve minor problems and i switch the call for `super.onCreate()` from first to last statement....

now some users are getting

```
Caused by java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
       at androidx.collection.SimpleArrayMap.put(SimpleArrayMap.java:482)
       at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzin.zza(zzin.java:108)
       at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzid.onActivityCreated(zzid.java:11)
       at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityCreated(Application.java:221)
       at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:1071)
       at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:81)
       at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:154)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:312)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
       at com.tomatedigital.adinjector.AdsAppCompatActivity.onCreate(AdsAppCompatActivity.java:253)
       at com.tomatedigital.giveawaymaster.activity.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:132)
       at com.tomatedigital.giveawaymaster.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:623)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7258)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7249)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1222)
```

the app is in production over 5k daily users but i wont be able to replicate the error in dev...

does anyone have any idea what might be

Comment: please add supporting codes for debugging

Comment: This is a threading problem - you need to provide some code so that people can help you here.

Comment: @ligi, i know this is a concurrency problem but MY CODE HAS ZERO THREAD CREATION NOR MANIPULATION and as you can see from the stack trace the exception happens inside one of googles api... my question is related to... "does super.onCreate() turns any important flag that must be the first statement on android activites?"

Comment: no it shouldn't be, because I tried that and not getting crash

Answer (score 1):

As per logs and my understanding...

`super.onCreate()` call in last is not main reason of crash.

This error is reason of concurrent modification in your HashMap (you have taken) and multiple threads are trying to access and edit in that HashMap.

Because...

HashMap is **non synchronized**. It is not-thread safe and can't be shared between many threads without proper synchronization code whereas **Hashtable** is synchronized....

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here:

[image]

And here:

[image]

The `super` callback has to be called first, to avoid errors due to the incompleteness of the `Activity` creation.

Screenshots source: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#java

Comment: although your answer is right and the documentation is clear about that, that is not the real cause of my crash.  you can check more info in my own answer thanks for helping

Comment: I think to understand the cause of your crash, we'd need to see the code

Answer (score 1):

I just found this an issue in the new `firebase-core` and `firebase-analytics` apis im importing.

to solve it i need to downgrade

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
```

for futher information please refer to this.
[java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in activity onCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59916267/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-in-activity-oncreate)

Answer (score 0):

Its `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` bug. they fixed it in version 17.2.3 see changelog: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#analytics_v17-2-3