# How to solve ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

After updating the App I get errors from `Firebase` almost in all activities.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.app/com.project.app.MainActivity}: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11()
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)

Caused by java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
   at androidx.collection.SimpleArrayMap.put(SimpleArrayMap.java:482)
   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzin.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.2.2:108)
   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzid.onActivityCreated(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.2.2:11)
   at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityCreated(Application.java:199)
   at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:1034)
   at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:81)
   at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:149)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:313)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
   at com.project.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:74)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7088)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7079)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11()
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

I am sure the problem appeared after changing `build.gradle` (Module:app).

This is some lines of `build.gradle` (old version):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta3'
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
```

This is some lines of `build.gradle` (new version):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.3.0'
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
```

I think is due to firebase-analytics:17.2.2, but I'm not sure. 
How do you think where is the problem? And Do I need to downgrade to the old version?

Comment: If all you've done is a basic integration without writing any code, then you should contact Firebase support directly, as the problem appears to be inside the SDK.  Make sure you are using the latest version. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Did you recently upgrade any androidx library?

Comment: Yes. I upgraded constraintLayout. See my message please, I wrote it in build.gradle (new version)

Comment: Having same issue, in other questions people revert com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2 library version to 17.2.1 or lower.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60005457/1775292

Comment: I'm facing the same issues after upgrading my mobile ads sdk.

Comment: @Dmitrijs After downgrading the library to 17.2.1, the errors disappeared. But Firebase support says the errors are related to Material components

Comment: @TImWeb I don't think so, my app does not have Material components. Chick linked question, I posted a few solutions there.

Answer (score 5):

Its because firebase-core lib 
they fixed it in version 17.2.3 see changelog: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#analytics_v17-2-3

change your

`'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'`

to

`'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.3'`

Comment: In my case I had this issue with Analytics version 17.2.2  (I don't have firebase-core dependency). After upgrading it to 17.2.3 the problem seems to be solved. Thanks!